# Disable or reset a CSS rule

Tags: css

If define a CSS rule with `top: 0;`, how can I later disable or neutralise it in favor of `bottom: 0;` used elsewhere?

Answer (score 85):

do `top: auto; bottom:0;` - `auto` is the default value for [`top`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_top.asp)

Comment: While `top: auto;` does answer the question in the description, it does not answer the question in the header which is how to disable or reset a css rule.

Answer (score 28):

```
top: auto;
bottom: 0px;
```

Answer (score 26):

if you have the stretch issue just use **initial** to reset the rule

```
top: initial;
```

or

```
bottom: initial;
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS is cascading, so for example, if you put `p { top: 0;)` first and `p.bottom {top:auto; bottom: 0;)` after that, your css will listen to the latter for p.bottom

Comment: yeah, but `bottom: 0` will not override `top: 0`, it'll just be added to the rules making the element stretch from top to bottom

Comment: Agreed, adding top: auto; to p.bottom like suggested by others will take care of that though.