# How to neutralize  CSS definitions without overriding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

Is there a way to neutralize CSS rules for an element without overriding everything?

For examble, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and it has many pre-defined CSS definitions for `table`. In some places, I don't want them.

On certain `table` elements, I'm wondering if I can do something like this:

```
<table style="default"></table>
```

Comment: cant you just remove the table part of bootstrap?

Comment: I dont want to do it because I use it in another places...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable a CSS rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396848/how-to-disable-a-css-rule)

Comment: @random It is not! I sow it. it doesn't help me. why to downvote?

Comment: Ask whoever downvoted you why they downvoted you. Don't go running around accusing people. Also, you don't mention you saw that earlier question.

Comment: @sh3211 - Please consider editing your question so it's more clear. Some people will downvote questions that they've spent time on only to discover the question-asker left out important, clarifying details. The question box gives you lots of space for a very good reason ;) For the sake of clarity, I am not the downvoter. I am out of votes for the day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not neutralize CSS rules whithout overriding. So you have to do as you suggested in the answers above.

Answer (score 7):

Bootstrap has [only a little bit](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/tables.less) of CSS for the `<table>` element:

```
table {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

To override these you could make a class for your table called strapless or something:

```
table.strapless{
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  border-color: gray;
}
```

This `table.strapless` selector will override the `table` selector used by bootstrap because it is [more specific](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

To use the css class include it in the class attribute of your table:

```
<table class="strapless">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class in your CSS to target different table elements.

```
table.black {
    background-color:black;
}

table.default {
    background-color:white;
}
```

You can then group your table elements and apply the specific styles that you intend to apply just simply by giving them the appropriate class attribute names on the elements themselves.

```
<table class="default">

<table class="black">
```

It's also important to note that CSS class definitions will override element definitions. A good rule of thumb is that more specific CSS selectors will override less specific selectors. Thus, you can apply different CSS styles from a new CSS file, if for some reason you don't want to modify your original CSS file. This of course assumes there isn't already a `table.default` rule and a `table.black` rule in the legacy CSS.

Comment: It's clear that you can do so. The question was if we can to neutralize many settings at once. I understand from your words that we can not do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your website's CSS should probably be in an external stylesheet if there is going to be a decent amount of it. In this stylesheet, you would do what others suggest which is to give your table a class name where you could add the CSS rules you want.

But then the real **key** in order to override Bootstrap's stylesheet with your newly applied CSS rule(s) in your, mysite.css, stylesheet is for this stylesheet to be placed **further down** on your HTML page than that of the bootstrap.css file. Like this:

External:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/assets/css/mysite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
</html>
```

If you don't want to go the external stylesheet route, then using "inline" rules as you suggested in your question will work (i.e., override bootstrap.css) too:

Inline:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
      <tr>
         <td style="border-top: 1px solid red;"></td>
         <td></td>
     </tr> 
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```