# Controlling a table row if it has bottom border or not

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap.
I have a table, where some rows needs to be grouped with the rows below them.
That means there should be no border between them.
I am wondering if there is an inherent bootstrap way of doing this, or do I need to 
put on each `tr style="..no border.."`
All I care is for the solution to work on Chrome (and nice to have on FF).

Comment: Can you provide some of your relevant HTML or CSS for this problem? This link might provide some help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474303/how-to-neutralize-css-definitions-without-overriding

Comment: The html is a straight forward <table><tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr></table> and the link u gave me is what I plan to do if I find no bootstrap solution. I am specificaly trying to see if there  is a BS solution, to learn the FW. How to solve this pure css/html, I know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Stuff</label>
        </td>
        <td>
           <label>sdrfg</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="group">
        <td>
            <label>Other stuff</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>asdfgh</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Other stuff</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>asdfgh</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table{
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table td{
    border-top:1px solid #000000;
}
table tr.group>td{
    border-top:none;
}
```

Comment: Since I am using Bootstrap. It should be only `
table tr.group>td{
    border-top:none;
}
` and the group class should be on the second element, which makes things much more easier from development perspective (easier to know u r part of group on the second element, not the first). Modify your answer and ill accept it

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka fair enough. So you want the table data to have borders rather than the table row?

Comment: This is how bootstrap has it (borders on the TD, not the TR).

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka is this right? Or is the class on the `<td>`?

Comment: I put the full answer in my comment, for this to work with bootastrap, all u need to add to your css is: ` table tr.group>td{ border-top:none; } `